# sap.m.pdfViewer not working properly in iPhone

Tags: ios, pdf, sapui5, local, display

`sap.m.pdfViewer` is working fine for displaying local PDF file in Android device. In iPhone it opens up PDF file and when the user taps on "Done" , the app freezes.

Below image is taken from XCODE simulator on Safari browser.

[image]

The PDF file is stored in `webapp` folder of application.

```
//defined below code in "onInit" 
this._pdfViewer = new PDFViewer(); 
this.getView().addDependent(this._pdfViewer); //code onbutton press event
var fileSrc = "";
fileSrc = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("app", "/docs/PrivacyStmt_de.pdf");
this._pdfViewer.setSource(fileSrc);
this._pdfViewer.open();
```

Please suggest ways to handle this issue. This is only happening for iOS device.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this issue still reproducible in newer UI5 versions? In that case, consider to create an issue on https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/new